# FBSDK Share button not working for sharing on friends timeline in xcode7

Tags: ios, facebook, xcode7, sharekit, fbsdk

I am using FBSDK sharebutton in my application using latest fbSDK for iOS & xcode 7,i want to share some information on friend's timeline from my app but when using FBSDK SHARE button only normal share dialog is opening with no option for sharing on friends timeline...i am using following code as per  ios9 fbSDK documentation

```
     -(void)shareOnFriendsTimeline
{
      FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
      content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com"];
      FBSDKShareButton *shareButton = [[FBSDKShareButton alloc] init];
      shareButton.shareContent = content;  
      shareButton.center = self.view.center;
      [self.view addSubview:shareButton];
}
```

please tell me where i am doing wrong...thanks in advance

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. Sharing to another person's timeline is not possible.

Comment: but with referennce to iOS9 fb SDK documentation , i think we can share on friends timeline ....  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/share-button

Comment: are the images shown  in the link wrong & do u have any documentation or  link by which i can know that share on friends timeline is not possible in iOS

Comment: Can you post an image of what it looks like for you with the dropdown?

Comment: i dont get any dropdown,i simply get a share dialog with only post option

Comment: Then I think my original assumption was correct. Are you sure it's not opening the web fallback?

Comment: You need to get permission from Facebook  in order to share on others wall. first upload your app in developers.facebook.com and follow all rules.

Comment: my app is already there in  developers.facebook.com....So should i ask for publish_permissions from user to share on friend's timeline?

Comment: Yes, for those sharing options you need to submit for review for the correct permission. See also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5.